# Android AVD / Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem with AVD. If I launch it from eclipse, load well but doesn't appear in screen. After that, I try it from terminal but I got the "Segmentation fault" message. Reading another topic I read that it is problem with 20 version of android SDK and to fix it, I should try: .../tools/emulator-arm @nameAVD. It works.

But I still have a problem, I need launch AVD from eclipse to debug applications! Can somebody help me?

Thak you a lot.

Comment: It's AVD actually, for Android Virtual Device.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us a bit more about your system, build, and what version of Android/Eclipse you are using?

if not, try uninstalling and re-installing eclipse, but use the Eclipse Classic version from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

then if it doesn't work still, try to delete and redownload the android SDK.

if that still doesn't work then chances are you have something wrong with your system settings

======================

EDIT*** here is a possible TEMPORARY solution..

only use Eclipse to clean/Build your projects, and use your terminal to install your app onto your emulator.

to build an APK without running, right click on your project, go to "Android Tools" and hit "Export Unsigned Package", which will prompt you to store the APK on to some place. Then, open up your AVD emulator and terminal. on your terminal, "cd" into the directory that you saved your APK file (like inside /...../Your Project/bin/) and then run the terminal command "adb install yourAPKfileName.apk"

this will automatically install the newest APK to your emulator and run it. since this process for building is a little slower than  usual, i would recommend only building/running when you need to, and always export the APK to the same place, and have your terminal open to the same place, so that when you press "up" on the terminal, it repeats the last command you used :)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 32 bits, JRE version 1.7.0_09 and I have tried with Eclipse Indigo and Juno. I have installed and deleted two times the android SDK.

I suppose that I have problems with my system setting but I do not know what is!

While I solve it, I am developping inside a virtual machine with the same configurations but it works fine. It is very strange...

Thanks

Comment: hmm... i can't replicate that build, so i can't help much with a permanent solution, sorry! But if you're okay with a TEMPORARY solution, look at my edited answer

Comment: The problem is solved. If I execute the AVD from a terminal typing:

emulator-arm @name_device -verbose it works fine.